# Help with understanding quotient ring structure

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-rings

> Let $R$ be the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/((x^2+x+1)(x^3+x+1))$ and $I$ be the ideal generated by $2$ in $R$. What is the cardinality of the ring $R/I$?

I am having a hard time understanding what the ring $\mathbb{R}/I$ should be. I know the formal definitions of quotient ring and the ring operations in it. However I cant make much of the structure of quotient rings. Could anyone make this simple for me?

Comment: $R/I\simeq \mathbb Z_2[x]/(f)$ and $|\mathbb Z_2[x]/(f)|=2^{\deg f}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Instead of thinking about the quotient directly, first write it down in a familiar form using third isomorphism theorem. After that, use Chinese Remainder Theorem to conclude.

I'm travelling, so will be able to shed more light after a while.

Comment: No need to use CRT since we don't need the ring structure to find the cardinality.

Comment: @user26857 I wanted to write down the quotient explicitly. But of course as far as the OP concerned, no need to use CRT.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same structure as $ \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/((x^2 + x + 1)(x^3 + x + 1)) $. By the Chinese remainder theorem, we have

$$ \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/((x^2 + x + 1)(x^3 + x + 1)) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^2 + x + 1) \times \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^3 + x + 1) = \mathbb{F}_4 \times \mathbb{F}_8 $$

The cardinality of this structure is clearly $ 32 $.

Comment: No need to use CRT since we don't need the ring structure to find the cardinality.

Comment: Sure, there is no harm in doing so, though :P

Comment: @Starfall Could you please explain why $\mathbb{Z}[x]/((x^2+x+1)(x^3+x+1))$  has the same structure as $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/((x^2+x+1)(x^3+x+1))$?

Comment: @Miz It doesn't, because you didn't mod out by $ 2 $ yet.

Comment: @Starfall I'm dont seem to understand what you mean by "This is the same structure as $ \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/((x^2 + x + 1)(x^3 + x + 1)) $" Could you please explain?

Comment: @Miz $ R/I $ is isomorphic to $ \mathbb Z_2[x]/((x^2+x+1)(x^3+x+1)) $.

Comment: @Starfall Would I be accurate in writing $\mathbb{Z}[x]/((x^2+x+1)(x^3+x+1)) = \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+x+1) \times \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^3+x+1)$?

Comment: @Miz No; those rings are not isomorphic. If you mod out by $ 3 $ on both sides, the ring on the left hand side has the nilpotent element $ (x^2 + x + 2)(x+2) $ of nilpotency index $ 3 $, whereas the ring on the right hand side has no elements with nilpotency index $ > 2 $.